# commandbutton doesn't call the action JSF

Tags: jsf, action, commandbutton

I have a problem in my Project:

My p:commandButton was working without a problem but after adding somme other dialog that are called from other p:commandButton the first one doesn't work anymore. I have tried to look for where the problem could be but I didn't get it.

Here is my button:

```
<h:form id="akteTable" style="width: 40%;float: left;">
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{projectM.akte == null}">

                <p:commandButton value="Add " onclick="dlg.show()" />
            </h:panelGroup>
            <h:panelGroup
                rendered="#{projectM.akte != null}">
                <p:dataTable value="#{projectM.service.akten}"
                    var="akte">
                    <p:column>
                                        ......
                                        </p:column>
                     </p:dataTable>
                <br />
                <p:commandButton value="Add akte" onclick="dlg.show()" />

            </h:panelGroup>
                   <p:dialog id="akteDialog" position="center" widgetVar="dlg"
                resizable="false">
                      <p:panelGrid id="editKrankenakte" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
                      ......
                        <f:facet name="footer">
             <p:commandButton value="Ok"
                action="#{projectM.addakte}"
                update=":akteTable, :Info, :einForm, :medForm"
                        oncomplete="dlg.hide()" />
                </f:facet>
              </p:panelGrid>
          </p:dialog>
              </h:form>
```

and here my ProjectM.java

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectManagement implements Serializable {

public void addakte() {
}
}
```

this methode addakte is not getting called.
Where is the Problem?

Thank u

Comment: solved it!!! I put 2 Dialogs outside <h:form> and gave each one its own <h:form>  : <p:dialog> <h:form>....

Comment: You might want to take some time to format your code properly in future. It's difficult to read as is